# Apollo and Prisma Graphql explicit model relationship not queryable

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma, resolver, prisma2

I have begun testing out prisma 2 and graphql in general for a new application. I am running into an issue with an explicit many to many table on being able to query relations.

Here is my apollo schema:

```
scalar DateTime

type Query {
    user(id: String!): User
    users: [User]
    spaces: [Space]
    roles: [Role]
}

type Mutation {
    createUser(id: String!, email: String!): User!
    createSpace(name: String!): Space!
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    spaces: [UserSpace!]
    createdAt: DateTime!
    updatedAt: DateTime!
}

type Space {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    users: [UserSpace!]
    createdAt: DateTime!
    updatedAt: DateTime!
}

type Role {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String!
    users: UserSpace
    createdAt: DateTime!
    updatedAt: DateTime!
}

type UserSpace {
    id: ID!
    user: User!
    space: Space!
    role: Role!
    createdAt: DateTime!
    updatedAt: DateTime!
}
```

Here is my prisma schema:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

// npx prisma migrate dev
// npx prisma generate

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model User {
  id String @id
  email String @unique
  spaces UserSpace[]
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Space {
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name String @unique
  users UserSpace[]
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Role {
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name String @unique
  description String
  users UserSpace[]
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model UserSpace {
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String
  space Space @relation(fields: [spaceId], references: [id])
  spaceId Int
  role Role @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  roleId Int
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

Here is my mutations resolver:

```
const { prisma } = require(".prisma/client");

async function createUser(parent, args, context, info) {
    return await context.prisma.user.create({
        data: {
            ...args,
        },
    });
}

async function createSpace(parent, args, context, info) {
    const isAuthenticated = context.authentication.isAuthenticated;
    let role = null;

    if(!isAuthenticated) {
        throw new Error("Not Authenticated");
    }

    try {
        role = await context.prisma.role.findUnique({
            where: {
                name: "Space Administrator",
            },
        });
    }
    catch(err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }

    return await context.prisma.space.create({
        data: {
            ...args,
            users: {
                create: {
                    role: { 
                        connect: { id: role.id },
                    },
                    user: {
                        connect: { id: context.authentication.auth0Id },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    });
}

module.exports = {
    createUser,
    createSpace,
}
```

Here is my user resolver (I know this is where the problem is however I do not know how to solve the issue):

```
function spaces(parent, args, context, info) {
    return context.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: parent.id } }).spaces();
}

module.exports = {
    spaces,
}
```

Basically when I create the space the user is added as a Space Administrator to the space and then should be able to be queried with the following:

```
query {
  users {
    id
    email
    spaces {
      id
      role {
        name
      }
      space {
        name
      }
    }
    createdAt
  }
}
```

However when I run the query I get the following error:

```
"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field UserSpace.role.",
```

How in prisma 2 do I make the resolver for the users work with an explicit many to many table and how it has the third relation in there? I am new to prisma and graphql so if there anything else that stands out also I would like to have the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the word `type` to refer to object-models in your GraphQL schema and `model` to refer to data-models in your Prisma Schema.

##### The Problem

I see that you have a `User` type resolver, that has a resolver function for `User.spaces` field in your `User` type. The query that you have defined in your `User.spaces` resolver will return the relevant `userSpace` records from the database.

However, these `userSpace` records do not by default resolve the `role` field, as it is a relation field. This is how prisma works (relation fields are not resolved by default, unless explicitly stated).

##### Solution

Create a resolver for the `UserSpace` type and explicitly define the  the resolver function for `UserSpace.role` field. This is what it will look like

```js
// UserSpace resolver module

function role(parent, args, context, info) {
    return context.prisma.userSpace.findUnique({ where: { id: parent.id } }).role();
}

module.exports = {
    role,
}
```

While there are some other ways to solve this problem, the way I have shown (along with the specific syntax) is recommended because under the hood it allows prisma to perform certain optimizations to [solve the n+1 query problem](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/query-optimization-performance#solving-the-n1-problem). But, if you don't know what that is, you don't necessarily need to worry about it either.

Comment: That makes more sense, this worked exactly how I wanted it to. I wish prisma would update their docs on the explicit many to many relations since those will more likely be common in the framework do to introspection.

Comment: Just to clarify, this behavior isn't limited to explicit many-to-many relations. Any relation field (and corresponding object) is not returned during a query by default (including implicit relation). 

You can change this behavior by using the ```include``` or ```select``` keyword and specifying the relation field. 

However, creating manual resolvers for each of these relaton fields (like i showed) is the best practise and avoids potential bugs/corner case issues.

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide the value to users arg? like this: `users(id: "string_value")`. Because is `id` is required.

Comment: Yeah id has a value, it appears however the users resolver cannot find the correct information so it always returns null. I believe this is because of the nature of that many to many having the third relation of roles.

Comment: I'm not understanding you comment? Are you saying it is impossible to do a relation table with three relations?

Comment: I'm not saying anything about Prisma but when you don't provide a required value these obvious happened because all of them tie together. that's how graphql works I said.